# Combine the content of couple of files with shared part of file name

Tags: r, unix

I have a number of files named in this way:

```
  1223_1_myCount.txt   
  1223_1_myCount2.txt       
  1223_2_myStatistic.txt
  1223_2_myDiscarded.txt  
  1223_3_myExample.txt    
  1223_3_myStatistic.txt   
  ................
```

For a total of 1000 couple of files. Is there a way to combine the content of the files two by two by matching *1*, equally for *2*, for *3* that is the only one part of the file name in common in the couple? For each combination of contents I would like also to write it on a file.

Comment: You want to combine the content of `1223_1_myCount.txt  & 1223_1_myCount2.txt` and `1223_2_myStatistic.txt & 1223_2_myDiscarded.txt` right?  What is the expected output file name?

Comment: Exactly!!! I will edit the question with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant ways to do this, but the following approach should work:

```
library(readtext)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
```

> Get file names from your working directory. The following code assumes only files of interest exist there. Otherwise you can filter with `grep(".txt",file_names)` etc.

```
file_names <- list.files(full.names = F)
```

> Read files from the list `file_names` into a dataframe `df` as rows using `map_dfr` from `purrr`

```
df  <- map_dfr(file_names,readtext)
```

> Create a new variable `file_index` to be used with `group_by` for concatenating text from files with identical `file_index` value (1, 2, or 3). Use `str_c` to collapse strings. You can change the pattern for `combo_file_name` within `paste` if you desire a different way to name the files containing the combined text

```
combo_data <- df %>%  mutate(file_index = sapply(strsplit(doc_id, "_"), "[", 2)) %>% group_by(file_index) %>% 
              summarize(combo_file_name = paste("combo_file",unique(file_index),sep="_") , combo_text = str_c(text, collapse = ", ")) %>%
              ungroup() %>% select(combo_file_name,combo_text)
```

> Create a function to write files using `combo_data` as input and save files as combo_1.txt, combo_2.txt etc.

```
write_file <- function (df_in){
  fileConn <- file(paste(df_in[1],".txt",sep=""))
  writeLines(df_in[2], fileConn)
  close(fileConn)
}

apply(combo_data,1,write_file)
```

> Use `getwd()` to find the working directory where the combined files are saved